# Is destroying dragula instance necessary for Angular components if the DOM will be removed anyway?

Tags: angular, dragula

Using [dragula](https://github.com/bevacqua/dragula) library in my Angular app (angular version 8) for drag/drop featutes. Do I have to call its `destroy` function when `ngDestroy()` hook is called by Angular?

The library's `destroy` function:

> Removes all drag and drop events used by dragula to manage drag and drop between the containers. If .destroy is called while an element is being dragged, the drag will be effectively cancelled.

All it does is to remove event listeners from the DOM. If the DOM itself is deleted by Angular, maybe there is no need to remove event listeners?

Please, explain if I am missing anything here.